# andengine empty TextureRegion

Tags: android, textures, andengine

I want to create a Sprite with its children. The Sprite will be empty but the children will not. So I need a TextureRegion to create the sprite. Such as sprite itself is empty, I don't need to create a texture from assets, but I need a Texture to create the sprite

```
new Sprite(pX, pY, pTextureRegion)
```

How can I create an empty TextureRegion for this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Entity](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/Entity.java) and Entity.attachChild().